# Sencha Touch 2 zoom panel content

Tags: javascript, extjs, zooming, sencha-touch-2

Is there any plugin for pinch to zoom in ST2. I need a simple zooming of html loaded inside sencha panel. Any ideas are welcome!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [PinchZoomImage](http://goo.gl/iUuyp.) in sencha market

Comment: I found a bug. You can drag the image out of the initial boundaries. Would be great to have a fix for that :)

Comment: Hey @Sang Oh to reproduce the bug you need to first zoom a little in and once you are zoomed you can drag the image out of the boundaries which is not cool ;-) Can we get that fixed?

Comment: I got a fix for it. It's not really polished though. Would be cool to get you involved!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there are any available plugins, but I did stumble accross a git that looks like it has the functionality you are looking for: https://gist.github.com/1002303

Comment: It's ST1. OP's looking for a ST2 plugin. Also, from the code, I'm quite sure it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the [pinch zoom with carousel](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?197903-Pinch-Image-with-carousel-and-working-fine) code from the Sencha Touch forum?

Comment: Please expand your answer with more context from the linked article. It will help further visitors and avoid link rot.

Comment: The linked words say it all: it is a JS code for a "pinch image zoom with carousel", posted on the official Sencha Touch forum that answers a question similar to the one asked by innerJL.